# Copy last 5 updated files in HDFS Hadoop to target folder in bash

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, awk, hdfs

I am trying to select the last 5 latest updated files and copy them into a target folder in hdfs (Hadoop) using bash script. I have this command that returns the last 5 most recent files:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/myfolder | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}' | sort -k6,7 | tail -5
```

Output

```
/user/myfolder/example1.txt
/user/myfolder/example2.txt
/user/myfolder/example3.txt
/user/myfolder/example4.txt
/user/myfolder/example5.txt
```

What would be a good approach for the next step to move these files to a target hdfs directory?

Edit:

So I found out the hdfs dfs -cp command can take multiple arguments like so:

```
latest_files=$(hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/myfolder | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}' | sort -k6,7 | tail -5 | cut -d" " -f3)
hdfs dfs -cp $latest_files $target_directory
```

Also, I believe the accepted answer using xargs is a good choice as well.

Comment: you  want to copy from one location in HDFS to another location in HDFS ??

Comment: Yeah I think this is mainly a question on bash scripting though.

Comment: so you want to build the  cp itself using the awk ?

Comment: I was thinking this would be the approach. Unless there is some other better option?

Comment: `hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/myfolder | awk -F" " '{print "hdfs dfs -cp "$6" "$7" "$8 "/target_directory"}' | sort -k6,7 | tail -5` that should work , but I have no way to test it though

Comment: @RobertoHernandez , not working!

Comment: what is it printing ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, it prints  `[devuser@DATANODEUK03 HADOOP]$ hadoop dfs -ls -R /user/myfolder | awk -F" " '{print "hdfs dfs -cp "$6" "$7" "$8 "/targetDirectory"}' | sort -k6,7 | tail -5
hdfs dfs -cp 2020-08-06 05:04 /user/myfolder/test17.txt/user/targetDirectory/
hdfs dfs -cp 2020-08-06 05:04 /user/myfolder/test18.txt/user/targetDirectory
hdfs dfs -cp 2020-08-06 04:51 /user/myfolder/test1.txt/user/targetDirectory/
hdfs dfs -cp 2020-08-06 04:51 /user/myfolder/test/test2.txt/user/targetDirectory/
hdfs dfs -cp 2020-08-06 04:53 /user/myfolder/test/test3.txt/user/targetDirectory/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the below command with `awk` & `xargs` solves the problem.

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /dev/hadoop/hdata/test | awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'|sort -nr| head -5| cut -d" " -f3- | xargs  -I{} hadoop fs -cp '{}' /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1
```

complete command validation:

```
#input files available
[devuser@DATANODEUK03 HADOOP]$ hadoop fs -ls /dev/hadoop/hdata/test
Found 8 items
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev          0 2020-08-06 04:51 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test1.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 04:56 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test10.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:00 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test15.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:01 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test16.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:04 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test17.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:04 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test18.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev          0 2020-08-06 04:51 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test2.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev          0 2020-08-06 04:53 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test/test3.txt

#command to get latest 5 files in a folder recursively & copy into another folder
hadoop fs -ls -R /dev/hadoop/hdata/test | awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'|sort -nr| head -5| cut -d" " -f3- | xargs  -I{} hadoop fs -cp '{}' /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1

#copy validation in HDFS
[devuser@DATANODEUK03 HADOOP]$ hadoop fs -ls /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1

Found 5 items
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:05 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1/test10.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:05 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1/test15.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:04 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1/test16.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:04 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1/test17.txt
-rw-r-----   3 devuser uk1-dna-haas_dev         21 2020-08-06 05:04 /dev/hadoop/hdata/test1/test18.txt
```